How to compute probability of isotope combinations?
I was solving these two questions:

Natural abundances of  $\ce{^{12}C}$ and $\ce{^{13}C}$ isotopes of carbon are 99% and 1%, respectively. Assuming they only contributes to the mol. wt. of $\ce{C2F4}$, the percentage of $\ce{C2F4}$ having a molecular mass of 101 is [?]


Oxygen consists of $\ce{^{16}O}$, $\ce{^{17}O}$ and $\ce{^{18}O}$ isotopes and carbon consists of isotopes of $\ce{^{12}C}$ and $\ce{^{13}C}$. Total number of $\ce{CO2}$ molecules possible is:
(1) 6
(2) 12
(3) 18
(4) 1 [?]

In the first question, I calculated the percentage as 1.98% by subtracting the percentage of the other two cases, with both C-12 and both C-13:
$$1 - (0.99 \times 0.99 + 0.01 \times 0.01) = 0.0198 = 1.98%$$
The answer indicates that we have to consider C-12, C-13 and C-13, C-12 as separate cases. It doesn't make intuitive sense to me. Aren't they the same? If we consider them to be the same we get a percentage of 0.99%, which is incorrect as it doesn't add up to 100.
C-12 and C-13  (mass of 101): $0.99\times0.01 = 0.0099 = 0.99%$
Does this mean I have to consider a case where I take C-13 first and then C-12? How does that make sense?
In the second question the answer is 12. If we use the same condition of giving importance to the order, the possibilities would be greater. I don't understand this and would appreciate some help. Has it got something to do with the structures maybe? How do I know when I have to consider them separately?

If an isotope is present at $x$% then two of the same are present as $x^2$%, using this you should be able to work out  an answer.

Be aware that text is preferred to be provided as text, not as a screenshot. Or at least essential parts, if the text is long or not easy to "textify".

It is not matter of chemistry, but of combinatorics and multiplicity of identical states. In two coin flipping, head+tail has  probability 0.5, have multiplicity 2 (head+tail and tail+head).

The order does not matter, but the probabilities for each carbon must be considered as distinct. It's easier to understand, perhaps, if one thinks of flipping coins, α and β, with 12C on one face, and 13C on the other.
The coins can come up:

α: 12C & β:12C; sum = 24
α: 12C & β:13C; sum = 25
α: 13C & β:12C; sum = 25
α: 13C & β:13C; sum = 26

If the probabilities were 50%/50%, then twice as many come up 25 as 24 or 26. Since they're not 50/50, then the natural occurrence of the isotopes must be included as factors.
Another comparison would be to the Punnett square, used to predict genotypes of crossbreeds, where parents are the same hybrid.
